# Is the hadith about Sun and other heavenly bodies being created after Earth authentic?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, authenticity, science, creation, universe

In this narration itsays that this is sahih but I don't know if all scholars think the same.

A sound tradition from the Messenger of God told us by Hannad b. al-Sari, who also said that he read all of the hadith (to Abu Bakr)- Abu Bakr b. 'Ayyash- Abu Sa'd al-Baqqal- 'Ikrimah- Ibn Abbas: The Jews came to the Prophet and asked him about the creation of the heavens and the earth. He said: God created the earth on Sunday and Monday. He created the mountains and the uses they possess on Tuesday. On Wednesday, He created trees, water, cities and the cultivated barren land. These are four (days). He continued (citing the Qur'an): 'Say: Do you really not believe in the One Who created the earth in two days, and set up others like Him? That is the Lord of the worlds. He made it firmly anchored (mountains) above it and blessed it and decreed that it contain the amount of food it provides, (all) in four days, equally for those asking'- for those who ask. On Thursday, He created heaven. On Friday, He created the stars, the sun, the moon, and the angels, until three hours remained. In the first of these three hours He created the terms (of human life), who would live and who would die. In the second, He cast harm upon everything that is useful for mankind. And in the third, (He created) Adam and had him dwell in Paradise. He commanded Iblis to prostrate himself before Adam, and He drove Adam out of Paradise.....

(Al-Tabari, Abu Ja’far, Tarikh ar-Rusul wal Muluk, Vol.1, 22)

Now there is already a question about this hadith on this site but there is no answer for it so I wanted to post it again since it was bothering me too. Maybe someone will answer this time. If this is sound, how do we understand this? We know that Sun and stars etc were created way before Earth was created. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/356428/

Comment: @UmH Thank you I didn't know some scholars classified this as weak.

Answer (score -1):

Hadith about the Creation
جاء في صحيح مسلم تحت باب " ابتداء الخلق " عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه أنه قال: " أخذ رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بيدي فقال : ( خلق الله عز وجل التربة يوم السبت ، وخلق فيها الجبال يوم الأحد ، وخلق الشجر يوم الاثنين ، وخلق المكروه يوم الثلاثاء ، وخلق النور يوم الأربعاء ، وبث فيها الدواب يوم الخميس ، وخلق آدم عليه السلام بعد العصر من يوم الجمعة في آخر الخلق ، في آخر ساعة من ساعات الجمعة ، فيما بين العصر إلى الليل ) .
It came in Sahih Muslim under the chapter “The Beginning of Creation” on the authority of Abu Hurairah, may God be pleased with him, that he said: “The Messenger of God, may God bless him and grant him peace, took my hand and said: (God Almighty created the soil on Saturday, and He created the mountains on Sunday, and He created the trees on Monday, He created the abomination on Tuesday, and He created the light on Wednesday, and He spread the beasts in them on Thursday, and He created Adam, peace be upon him, after the afternoon prayer of Friday at the end of creation, in the last hour of Friday hours, between afternoon and night)
4.543 billion years
1-  Here we see that the prophet could have eluted that the earth age is considered to be 7 days span. That will make the day length is: 4.543x1000/7 = 649 Millions of years.
In this manner we can conclude that: In the first 649M years Allah created the Soil of the earth in the phenomena called: Mass accretion. The Earth obviously took its round spherical form during this period and probably started the volcanic activities on it’s surface.

In the second day, which is from 650 M to 1298 M of years, Allah created the mountains in the Earth due to Volcanic activities or plate tectonics. Although, the plate tectonics theory has a lot of problems explaining the correct shape of continent.

In the third day: 1299 M to 1947 M Allah created the Trees. Remember that the Sun was always there, and during the first and second day the Earth was still covered with cloud of gas from the birth of the Solar system and the solar wind was working during this time to clear the Earth and the surrounding space from all of this gas. The gas got carried away by the solar wind, where the dust was settled on earth or on the various objects floating in the nearby space.
In addition to that the trees need Sun to grow, they also need water. We can conclude that the water has started here on Earth in the first, second or third day.

In the Fourth day: 1948 M to 2596 M Allah created the abomination, this could be when the Earth went into the deep freeze and we had Africa and the rest of the equator countries frozen solid like Antarctica today, or it can be talking about the creation of bacteria and viruses. It could be also that a large collision happened to Earth. All what we can conclude with certainty that a bad thing happened on this day, but this bad thing was essential for the development of life on Earth.

Up to this point, if we compare the list of items listed in Quran in the first 4 days is as follows:
Earth, Mountains, food, blessings as per the Quran.
Earth, mountains, Trees, and the abomination on the fourth day. This way the hadith and the Quran goes together without contradiction. If we consider the abomination are the bacteria and viruses, then we can see how people hate this, but at the same time it is blessing from Allah as nothing functions in our life without the bacteria and viruses. For that we can consider it as a blessing at the same time.

In the Fifth day: 2597 M to 3245 M, Allah created the light. Here we know that the Sun should have been present and it would have been shining on Earth due to the presence of trees on Earth. But here the prophet could be talking about the moon. So the Creation of the moon has happened according to this hadith about 1298 to 1947 M years ago. That contradicts the accepted notion among scientists of the creation of the moon at the 4425 M years.
Compare it again to the Quran, on the 5th and 6th day, Allah was creating and rearranging the rest of the planets in the Solar system, for that now we can see that the creation of the moon on that day coincide with the Quran.

In the Sixth day: (3246 M to 3894 M years) Allah created the animals and the beasts. This would have been anywhere from 649 to 1298 M years ago. So, we can notice the correlation between the moon and the life on Earth, once the moon was established, it stabilized the Earth rotation, and it looks like life started after that or it took major boost due to the normalization of the temperature and the climate.

In the day Seven: 649 M years till present, in this period everything was ready on Earth for humanity life to start. However, Allah did not start it at the beginning of the seventh day, but the hadith put the creation of Adam at the last hour of the Seventh day (Friday) right before the Sunset. The prophet is insinuating that the Sunset would be the start of the day of Judgment. For that if Adam was created 30 or 60 thousand years ago, then it is very accurate to say he was created in the last hour of the seventh day.

In order to check if this understanding is correct, we can find in the surah that Allah says in Six days that are equal in length. For that this Hadith of the prophet gave us the explanation of what those six days are.